# How to convert [String : String?] to [NSObject : AnyObject]! in Swift 2.0 for Firebase Api?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

How can i convert [String : String?] to [NSObject : AnyObject]!?

Right now my project using [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) as a backend for Swift app.
After i updated to Xcode 7 and swift 2.0,

I got an error with .updateChildValues function like and image below.
[image]

How can i fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the values in the dictionary are of type `String?`, and so they could contain `nil`. When the dictionary is passed to Objective-C code in Firebase, it's converted to an `NSDictionary`. Values in an `NSDictionary` can't be `nil`.

I'm guessing `self.deckName.text` or `self.deckDetails.text` is returning a `String?` instead of a `String` as part of an SDK update in Xcode 7. If you're absolutely certain that they will never return `nil`, you can add an exclamation point after `self.deckName.text` and/or `self.deckDetails.text` to unwrap from `String?` to `String`.

Note that if you make a bad assumption and something does return `nil`, your program will crash. If you're uncertain, you could do something like `self.deckName.text ?? ""`, which means "return deckName.text if it's not nil, otherwise return an empty string".